# Swagger UI version 3 returning a 404 page but api-docs is working

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I am trying to setup swagger-UI to test my springboot REST API rather than using postman however after going through a few tutorials and some questions i can not seem to get past the 404 error when trying to access the html page via my browser.

My dependencies :

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

SpringConfig:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

and my controller

```java
@Controller
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public class AppController {

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(path ="/api")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    @GetMapping(path = { "/api/Teacher/{id}"})
    public TeacherPayload getTeacher(@PathVariable(required=false,name="id") String id) throws 
    Exception{

        if (id != null) {
            return teacher.getTeacher(id);

        } else {
            return teacher.getTeachers();

        }

....
```

I changed my port number fro the default 8080 to 3005 but i do not think that should be the problem as i tried reverting back to 8080 to no avail.

Edit: My security config is as follows, note i permitted all paths to bypass the security whilst testing

```java
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/authenticate");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/recoverPortal");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.cors();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request

                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/newUser").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/newUser").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/resetPassword").authenticated()// all other requests need to be authenticated
                        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What endpoint are you hitting? It should be `/swagger-ui/` at the end, not `/swagger-ui.html`. Also, I think you can omit the `springfox-swagger-ui` dependency. All I need in my setup is the `springfox-boot-starter` one.